# Use enum value as generic parameter doesn't work with enums with more then one value

Tags: typescript

I've found a situation where it makes a difference if an Enum in typescript has 1 or more values and I don't get why.

Look at this simplified example code:

```
// library code

interface Action<T = any> {
    type: T
}

interface SpecialAction<T = any> extends Action<T> {
    id: string
    timestamp: Date
}

function enhance<T>(action: Action<T>): SpecialAction<T> {
    return {
        ... action,
        id: "some-id",
        timestamp: new Date()
    }
}

// users code

enum ActionTypes {
    A = "A"
}

interface UserAction extends SpecialAction<ActionTypes.A> {}

const value: UserAction = enhance({
    type: ActionTypes.A
})
```

This works perfectly fine. However, if I change the enum like this:

```
enum ActionTypes {
    A = "A",
    B = "B"
}
```

then the I get the following compile error in the line with `const value: UserAction = enhance({`:

```
Type 'SpecialAction<ActionTypes>' is not assignable to type 'UserAction'.
    Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
        Type 'ActionTypes' is not assignable to type 'ActionTypes.A'.
```

If I change the code to:

```
const value: UserAction = enhance<ActionTypes.A>({
    type: ActionTypes.A
})
```

the error is gone and everything works fine again.

So my assumption is that when the enum has only a single value then typescript infers the type `T` to be `ActionTypes.A`. But if the enum has more then one value then Typescript can't infer this anymore?
But why is this the case? In the given example the information that `T` is `ActionTypes.A` is clearly defined in the object literal

```
{
    type: ActionTypes.A
}
```

But the more general question is: 
Why does the number of enum values matter for the compiler?
Isn't this dangerous because it could break behavior in unexpected ways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a whole lot of stuff that happens when TypeScript encounters a value of a literal `string`/`number`/`enum` type.  Sometimes the compiler will widen the type to `string`/`number`/the-relevant-`enum`.  Other times the compiler will leave the type as the literal value.  It's not incredibly simple to describe which one will happen where.  You can [read all about it](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676) if you dare.

In your case, you have a generic type parameter `T` in `enhance()` that you'd like to be inferred as the narrow literal type `ActionTypes.A`, but is actually inferred as `ActionTypes`, the union of each literal type that makes up the `enum`.  If `ActionTypes.A` is the only element, then the types `ActionTypes` and `ActionTypes.A` are identical, and you don't see a problem.  But when `ActionTypes` is equivalent to `ActionTypes.A | ActionTypes.B`, you run into the problem, because `enhance()`'s return type becomes `SpecialAction<ActionTypes>` and not `SpecialAction<ActionTypes.A>` like you expect.  And you can't assign a `SpecialAction<ActionTypes>` value to a `SpecialAction<ActionTypes.A>` without checking it first or using a type assertion.

Again, you want `T` to be inferred as `ActionTypes.A`.  Indeed, if you manually specify the type parameter `T`, as in `enhance<ActionTypes.A>(...)`, it works.  How can we get the compiler to infer the narrower type for `T`?  Well, it turns out that if you place a special [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) that includes `string` or `number` on the generic type, the compiler will take that as a hint that you mean for the type to be as narrow as possible.  For example:

```
declare function wide<T>(t: T): T;
let s = wide("abc"); // s is of type string
let n = wide(123); // n is of type number
declare function narrow<T extends string>(t: T): T;
let ss = narrow("abc"); // ss is of type "abc"
let nn = narrow(123); // error, 123 does not extend string
```

The special constraint can even be a union of types, as long as one of the elements of the union contains `string` or `number` and isn't absorbed by something else:

```
type Narrowable = string | number | boolean | symbol | object | void | undefined | null | {};
declare function betterNarrow<T extends Narrowable>(t: T): T; 
let sss = betterNarrow("abc"); // sss is of type "abc"
let nnn = betterNarrow(123); // nnn is of type 123
let bbb = betterNarrow(true); // bbb is of type true
```

Here, `Narrowable` is essentially the same as `unknown` or `any` in that just about anything is assignable to it.  But since it is a union of things that contains `string` and `number` as elements it serves as a hint to narrow in generic constraints.  (Note that `type Narrowable = string | number | unknown` wouldn't work, since that would become just `unknown`.  It's tricky.)

So finally we can alter `enhance()` to give it that narrowing hint:

```
type Narrowable = string | number | boolean | symbol | object | void | undefined | null | {};
function enhance<T extends Narrowable>(action: Action<T>): SpecialAction<T> {
  return {
    ...action,
    id: "some-id",
    timestamp: new Date()
  }
} 

const value: UserAction = enhance({
  type: ActionTypes.A
}) // no error
```

It works!  Hope that helps. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. I haven't fully understood the narrowable thing yet but it helps a lot and I will play around with it to get a better understanding of the details.