# typescript how to test if two generics are equivalent?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-typings

What I wish to accomplish is something along the line of:

```
type AType<T, U> = (T is Equal U) ? T : [T, U]
```

[EDIT] base on a comment let me rephrase by a practical example:
Let's assume T is a `UInt8Array` the equality is if U is also a `UInt8Array`.
The equivalence is defined by the same type.

[EDIT 2]
Based on @daniel-hilgarth answers
It doesn't work as `T extends U` in practical usage (see below) if we assume T and U are numbers, T will be casted to the instance of the number passed, as in T won't be a `number` but T will be a `2` that extends the type `number`. So if U is `3` it won't extend `2`

Sorry if it's unclear, please check implementation below

```
type AType<T, U> = T extends U ? U extends T ? T : [T, U] : [T, U]

const fn = <T extends string | number, U extends string | number>(
  x: T,
  y: U,
): AType<T, U> => {
  throw new Error ('Yet to implement !')
}

const a = fn (2, 2)    // correct number
const b = fn (2, 's')  // correct [number, string]
```

but

```
const c = fn (2, 3)    // incorrect [number, number]
```

What i need is not:

- if `T extends U`

But:

- if `T extends` whatever `U extends`

I hope it clarifies the question.

Can it be done?

Comment: How do you define equivalence? Same structure? Or actually, the same type?

Comment: What i wish is two find out if the two generics types extends the same type - and according to that information returns different type using conditional    So they're should be of the same type .  -  -  For instance let's assume T is a `UInt8Array` what i want to check is if U is also a `UInt8Array`

Comment: For your question about `2` vs `number` in inference, see the `Narrowable` section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53527026/2887218).  TypeScript usually widens types from string/number/boolean literals to `string`/`number`/`boolean` in generics, unless you use a special constraint (which `Narrowable` will do for you).

Comment: red, understood and used @jcalz ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, for conditional types there is only one question that you can ask: `extends`. There is no equal, but we can simulate it by using two checks:

```
type AType<T, U> = T extends U ? U extends T ? T : [T, U] : [T, U]
```

First, we check if  `T` extends `U`. If so, we check if `U` extends `T`. Both conditions can only be true at the same time if `T` and `U` are of the exact same type, so we return `T`.

This works correctly in Typescript 3.2:

[image: proof]

([link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20AType%3CT%2C%20U%3E%20%3D%20T%20extends%20U%20%3F%20U%20extends%20T%20%3F%20T%20%3A%20%5BT%2C%20U%5D%20%3A%20%5BT%2C%20U%5D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20x%3CT%2C%20U%3E(t%3A%20T%2C%20u%3A%20U)%3A%20AType%3CT%2C%20U%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20null%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20y%20%3D%20x(3%2C%202)%3B%0D%0A))

Also, worth reading for an understanding of Conditional Types in general: https://koerbitz.me/posts/a-look-at-typescripts-conditional-types.html

Comment: Thank for your answer, but it's incorrect - not easy to explain, i've edited my question for a better understanding of the issue in your posted solution

Comment: Which Typescript version are you using?

Comment: In the typescript playground it seems to work correctly, see updated answer

Comment: yup i do see that - typescript i use is 3.2 ... do not see why it doesn't work in my ide :/

Comment: got it working - not sure how - thanks a lot for your answer